# Как написать конструктор копирования

Tags: c++, конструктор-копирования

```
class Class
{
private:
    int x;
public:
Class()
{
    x=10;
}
Class()//копирования
{
    ???//не знаю что написать
}
void change()
{
    x+=10;
}
};


void main ()
{
    Class a;
    Class b(a);
    a.change();
    //чтобы менялся один объект(a) и не менялся другой(b)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Class
{
private:
    int x;
public:
Class()
{
    x=10;
}

Class(const Class&) = default; //копирования

void change()
{
    x+=10;
}
};
```

Пожалуйста.

Comment: видно я не правильно написал. мне нужна копия объекта независящая в последствие от оригинала